# In Travis CI, can I run a script after all of my build matrix has succeeded?

Tags: python, travis-ci

I'm using Travis CI to build my Python project.  I'd like to test my project against different versions of Python, but then have a script that runs only if all of them are successful.

For example, this travis.yml doesn't do the job, since the after_success part runs after each of the Python builds:

```
language: python
python:
  - '2.7'
  - '3.2'
script:
  - python setup.py test
after_success:
  - # this runs both on 2.7 and 3.2
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

We are working on something like this, but unfortunately it's not possible right now directly from Travis.

You could use webhooks for this, which would make a request to a URL for you. Depending on what you need, this may work for you.

Comment: Thanks Henrik! Do you have any idea of the timescale for this?

Comment: It looks like this is being tracked at https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/929

Comment: @henrikhodne Where can I read about how to set this up with webhooks?

Answer (score 1):

There are solutions at https://github.com/alrra/travis-after-all and https://github.com/dmakhno/travis_after_all .

It's not as clean in the .travis.yml file as your proposal, which (as noted by trask) is currently on hold as described at https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/929; the developers say "we are aware of the request but don't have an ETA on when it will be ready."

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with the [Build Stages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/) feature (currently in Beta).

In your specific case, you would add something such as:

```
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: deploy
      script: ./deploy
      python:
        - '2.7'
        - '3.2'
```

to your `.travis.yml`.

See [this page](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/matrix-expansion/) for an example.

(Note I've redefined `python` in the deploy stage, as by default it would just take the first value from the matrix as defined in the default (`test`) job.  I haven't tested that but I'm assuming matrix expansion works in build stages.)